# How to parse WSDL file and how to post and Get data from the SAP server

Tags: iphone, ios5

Please help me how to use WSDL URL/file and how to post data and get data from the SAP server

Comment: You can write some code, then compile and run it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the 3rd party sdk for using the WSDL services, you can download the appropriate sdk for your services by entering your WSDL services url in the below link and download the sdk and integrate that to your project for using wsdl services easily.  http://sudzc.com/

Similarly, for checking the wsdl services response use this link http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html

This will helps you...:-)